# add a group of links in html

Tags: html

i have a word file with 100 different hyperlinks. 
Eg: 
   http://word1.com
   http://word2.com
   upto http://wordn.com

I have to create a html file with these n links.
like word1 which has a hyperlink to word1.com, word2 which has a hyperlink to word2.com etc

Any easy way to do this? rather than copy pasting the link and writing the code?

Comment: Well if it wasn't in a Word file, but in a .txt file (or anything holding ASCII) for example, it would be really easy to write a console app or something to consume the file and output an HTML file.  You CAN do the same with a Word file, its just more difficult and annoying to use the MS Word API.

Comment: is it one link per line?  use a macro.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JavaScript loop to do this.  Such as the for loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
{ 
    document.write('<a href="http://www.word' + i + '.com">Word' + i + '</a>');
}
```

like so...

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but i hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple loop and create an anchor in each run. Use the `.setAttribute("href", "word"+count+".com")` where `count` keeps incrementing, using Javascript. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBbA2/)